# Boost Dijkstra code not working?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, dijkstra

I'm trying to use vertices and edges from an input file to create a graph and then find the shortest paths using the boost dijkstra algorithm. So far, I'm using this code to read the input file which looks like

```
Vertices:
A,B,C,D,E
Edges:
(A, B, 3)
(B, C, 4)
(C, D, 5)
(A, E, 6)
(C, E, 2)
```

Code

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/prim_minimum_spanning_tree.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

int main(){
typedef int Weight;
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, Weight> WeightProperty;
typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string> NameProperty;
typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int> IndexProperty;

typedef boost::adjacency_list < boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
    NameProperty, WeightProperty > Graph;

typedef boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor Vertex;

typedef boost::property_map < Graph, boost::vertex_index_t >::type IndexMap;
typedef boost::property_map < Graph, boost::vertex_name_t >::type NameMap;

typedef boost::iterator_property_map < Vertex*, IndexMap, Vertex, Vertex& > PredecessorMap;
typedef boost::iterator_property_map < Weight*, IndexMap, Weight, Weight& > DistanceMap;

Graph g;

typedef boost::tokenizer < boost::char_separator<char> >
    tokenizer;

std::map<std::string, Vertex> Vmap;

//Initializes a graph and variables
Vertex u;
Vertex v;
char_separator<char> sep(",");
string filename = "";
string line = "";
string v1 = "";
string v2 = "";
fstream f;
Weight weight = 0;

//Prompts the user for the file name
std::cout << "Please enter the name of the text file: ";
std::cin >> filename;

//Opens the file and adds vertices and edges to graph g
f.open(filename);
getline(f, line);                                                                   //Ignores first line "Vertices:"
getline(f, line);
tokenizer tokens(line, sep);                                                        //Tokenizes the second line "Location1, Location2 ..." 
for (tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tokens.begin();
    tok_iter != tokens.end(); ++tok_iter) {
    Vmap[*tok_iter] = add_vertex(*tok_iter, g);                                     //For each token, add the value as a vertex in Graph g                                      
}

getline(f, line);                                                                   //Skip next line "Edges: "
while (!f.eof()){
    getline(f, line);
    line = line.substr(1, line.size() - 2);                                         //Removes parentheses by creating a substring without the first and last char
    tokenizer tokens(line, sep);                                                    //Tokenizes the string
    for (tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tokens.begin();
        tok_iter != tokens.end(); ++tok_iter)
    {
        if (distance(tokens.begin(), tok_iter) == 0)                                //Sets first token "Location 1" to u
        {
            v1 = *tok_iter;
        }
        if (distance(tokens.begin(), tok_iter) == 1)                                //Sets second token "Location 2" to v
        {
            v2 = *tok_iter;
        }
        if (distance(tokens.begin(), tok_iter) == 2)                                //Sets third token "IntegerWeightValue" to weight
        {
            weight = stoi(*tok_iter);
        }
    }
    add_edge(Vmap[v1], Vmap[v2], weight, g);                                        //Adds weighted edge from Location 1 to Location 2 to Graph g
}

cout << "Please enter the starting node: ";
cin >> v1;
cout << "Please enter the ending node: ";
cin >> v2;
u = Vmap[v1];
v = Vmap[v2];

// Create things for Dijkstra
std::vector<Vertex> predecessors(num_vertices(g)); // To store parents
std::vector<Weight> distances(num_vertices(g)); // To store distances

IndexMap indexMap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g);
PredecessorMap predecessorMap(&predecessors[0], indexMap);
DistanceMap distanceMap(&distances[0], indexMap);

// Compute shortest paths from v0 to all vertices, and store the output in predecessors and distances
// boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, v0, boost::predecessor_map(predecessorMap).distance_map(distanceMap));
// This is exactly the same as the above line - it is the idea of "named parameters" - you can pass the
// prdecessor map and the distance map in any order.
boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, u, boost::distance_map(distanceMap).predecessor_map(predecessorMap));

std::cout << "distances and parents:" << std::endl;
NameMap nameMap = boost::get(boost::vertex_name, g);

BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(s, g, Graph)
{
    std::cout << "distance(" << nameMap[u] << ", " << nameMap[s] << ") = " << distanceMap[s] << ", ";
    std::cout << "predecessor(" << nameMap[s] << ") = " << nameMap[predecessorMap[s]] << std::endl;
}

// Extract a shortest path
std::cout << std::endl;

typedef std::vector<Graph::edge_descriptor> PathType;

PathType path;

// We want to start at the destination and work our way back to the source
for (Vertex p = predecessorMap[v]; // Start by setting 'u' to the destintaion node's predecessor
    p != u; // Keep tracking the path until we get to the source
    v = p, p = predecessorMap[v]) // Set the current vertex to the current predecessor, and the predecessor to one level up
{
    std::pair<Graph::edge_descriptor, bool> edgePair = boost::edge(p, v, g);
    Graph::edge_descriptor edge = edgePair.first;

    path.push_back(edge);
}

// Write shortest path
std::cout << "Shortest path from " << v1 << " to " << v2 << std::endl;
float totalDistance = 0;
for (PathType::reverse_iterator pathIterator = path.rbegin(); pathIterator != path.rend(); ++pathIterator)
{
    std::cout << nameMap[boost::source(*pathIterator, g)] << " -> " << nameMap[boost::target(*pathIterator, g)]
        << " = " << boost::get(boost::edge_weight, g, *pathIterator) << std::endl;

}

std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "Distance: " << distanceMap[Vmap[v2]] << std::endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No self contained sample. No sample input. Did any of my previous answers help you at all? Am I going to waste more time here?

Comment: @sehe my bad, i didn't realize you could do that

Comment: Still crashes parsing on my box. Can you test it? And post the exact working code?

Comment: @sehe ok, I've update the code in my question to contain the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get your input parsing with your sample code: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ebeaed2a24ca026)**

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 1) > this->size() (which is 0)
```

I suspect the graph reading code was to blame in the first place, since when I replaced it with something I understood¹:

```
//Opens the file and adds vertices and edges to graph g
using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
std::fstream f(filename);
f >> std::noskipws;

std::vector<std::string> names;
std::vector<parsing::edgedef> defs;
if (f >> phrase_match(
            "Vertices:" >> eol >> +alnum % ',' >> eol >> 
            "Edges:" >> eol >>
            ('(' >> +alnum >> ',' >> +alnum >> ',' >> int_ >> ')') % eol,
            blank, names, defs))
{
    for(auto& c : names)
        Vmap[c] = add_vertex(c, g);         // For each token, add the value as a vertex in Graph g

    for(auto& def : defs)
    {
        std::cout << def.s << " -> " << def.t << " (" << def.weight << ")\n";
        add_edge(Vmap[def.s], Vmap[def.t], def.weight, g);                          // Adds weighted edge from Location 1 to Location 2 to Graph g
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work as expected. I can't see anything wrong with the program logic beyond the parsing (which I haven't tried to fix), so I hope that helped.

The below program prints the following outputs for A->{C-E} searches (summarizing the output):

```
Shortest path from A to A                       Distance : 0
Shortest path from A to B                       Distance : 3
Shortest path from A to C B -> C = 4            Distance : 7
Shortest path from A to D B -> C = 4 C -> D = 5 Distance : 12
Shortest path from A to E                       Distance : 6
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90da90e27e4efda0)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
//#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
//#include <boost/graph/prim_minimum_spanning_tree.hpp>
//#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
//#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
//#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

typedef int Weight;
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, Weight>      WeightProperty;
typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string> NameProperty;

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, NameProperty, WeightProperty> Graph;

typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;

typedef boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_index_t>::type IndexMap;
typedef boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_name_t>::type NameMap;

typedef boost::iterator_property_map<Vertex*, IndexMap, Vertex, Vertex&> PredecessorMap;
typedef boost::iterator_property_map<int*, IndexMap, int, int&> DistanceMap;

typedef std::map<std::string, Vertex> VertexMap;

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT((parsing), edgedef, (std::string,s)(std::string,t)(Weight,weight))

int main() {
    Graph g;
    VertexMap Vmap;
    {
        //Prompts the user for the file name
        std::string filename = "";
        std::cout << "Please enter the name of the text file: ";
        std::cin >> filename;

        //Opens the file and adds vertices and edges to graph g
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        std::fstream f(filename);
        f >> std::noskipws;

        std::vector<std::string> names;
        std::vector<parsing::edgedef> defs;
        if (f >> phrase_match(
                    "Vertices:" >> eol >> +alnum % ',' >> eol >> 
                    "Edges:" >> eol >>
                    ('(' >> +alnum >> ',' >> +alnum >> ',' >> int_ >> ')') % eol,
                    blank, names, defs))
        {
            for(auto& c : names)
                Vmap[c] = add_vertex(c, g);         // For each token, add the value as a vertex in Graph g

            for(auto& def : defs)
            {
                std::cout << def.s << " -> " << def.t << " (" << def.weight << ")\n";
                add_edge(Vmap[def.s], Vmap[def.t], def.weight, g);                          // Adds weighted edge from Location 1 to Location 2 to Graph g
            }
        }
    }

    //Prompts user for starting and ending node
    std::string v1 = "";
    std::string v2 = "";

    std::cout << "Please enter the starting node: ";
    std::cin >> v1;
    std::cout << "Please enter the ending node: ";
    std::cin >> v2;

    std::cout << "From " << v1 << " to " << v2 << "; num_vertices: " << num_vertices(g) << "\n";

    auto const srce_vertex = Vmap[v1];
    auto dest_vertex = Vmap[v2];

    // Create things for Dijkstra
    std::vector<Vertex> predecessors(num_vertices(g)); // To store parents
    std::vector<Weight> distances(num_vertices(g));    // To store distances

    IndexMap indexMap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g);
    PredecessorMap predecessorMap(&predecessors[0], indexMap);
    DistanceMap distanceMap(&distances[0], indexMap);

    // Compute shortest paths from v0 to all vertices, and store the output in predecessors and distances
    // boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, v0, boost::predecessor_map(predecessorMap).distance_map(distanceMap));
    // This is exactly the same as the above line - it is the idea of "named parameters" - you can pass the
    // prdecessor map and the distance map in any order.
    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, srce_vertex, boost::distance_map(distanceMap).predecessor_map(predecessorMap));

    std::cout << "distances and parents:" << std::endl;
    NameMap nameMap = boost::get(boost::vertex_name, g);

    BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(curr_vertex, g, Graph)
    {
        std::cout << "distance("    << nameMap[srce_vertex] << ", "   << nameMap[curr_vertex]                 << ") = " << distanceMap[curr_vertex] << ", ";
        std::cout << "predecessor(" << nameMap[curr_vertex] << ") = " << nameMap[predecessorMap[curr_vertex]] << std::endl;
    }

    // Extract a shortest path
    std::cout << std::endl;

    typedef std::vector<Graph::edge_descriptor> PathType;

    PathType path;

                                                                                  // We want to start at the destination and work our way back to the source
    for (Vertex curr_vertex = predecessorMap[dest_vertex];                        // Start by setting 'srce_vertex' to the destination node's predecessor
            curr_vertex != srce_vertex;                                           // Keep tracking the path until we get to the source
            dest_vertex = curr_vertex, curr_vertex = predecessorMap[dest_vertex]) // Set the current vertex to the current predecessor, and the predecessor to one level up
    {
        std::pair<Graph::edge_descriptor, bool> edgePair = boost::edge(curr_vertex, dest_vertex, g);
        Graph::edge_descriptor edge = edgePair.first;

        path.push_back(edge);
    }

    // Write shortest path
    std::cout << "Shortest path from " << v1 << " to " << v2 << std::endl;
    float totalDistance = 0;
    for (PathType::reverse_iterator pathIterator = path.rbegin(); pathIterator != path.rend(); ++pathIterator)
    {
        std::cout << nameMap[boost::source(*pathIterator, g)] << " -> " << nameMap[boost::target(*pathIterator, g)]
                  << " = " << boost::get(boost::edge_weight, g, *pathIterator) << std::endl;

    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Distance: " << distanceMap[Vmap[v2]] << std::endl;
}
```

---

¹ (sorry, I realize your ability to comprehend my parsing probably matches my comprehension of your parsing code right now; it's about the test though :))

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clarifying. I just wanted to make sure it was a syntax error and not a logical one.

Thank you!

Comment: You what? ! What about all the stuff that was in your question (about getting the same distance each time etc. ...). I give up